# Radar SNR for a LFM Waveform

Tags: snr, matched-filter, radar, chirp

How do you estimate the detection SNR for a radar transmitting an LFM (chirp) waveform? I'm looking for an SNR equation that is a function of chirp bandwidth and compressed (or uncompressed) pulsewidth.

Do you use the uncompressed pulsewidth or the compressed pulsed width? Do you add a term for pulse compression gain (proportional to the time bandwidth product = bandwidth*pulsewidth?) to the radar range equation?

[image]

According to [Mahafza](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1439884951), "For a given set of radar parameters, and as long as  the  transmitted  pulse  remains  unchanged,  then  the  SNR  is  also  unchanged regardless of the signal bandwidth. More precisely, when pulse compression is used, the detection range is maintained while the range resolution is drastically improved by keeping the pulse width unchanged and by increasing the band-width."

[image]

Comment: I think the SNR you are talking about is the SNR without pulse compression, as matched filtering introduces the processing gain so you should also add this processing gain too.

Comment: you can also look here might be this will provide some help [signal detection- Pulse Compression SNR Gain](http://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/35072/pulse-compressionchirp-snr-gain?rq=1)

Answer (score 1):

With pulse compression, the [SNR improves by a factor equal to the time-bandwidth product (synonymous with pulse compression gain)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pulse_compression#Improving_the_SNR_through_pulse_compression).

In the equation you listed, $\tau$ can be interpreted as the uncompressed pulse width, in which case that you'd need to add a factor for the pulse compression gain.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that you'd only add a pulse compression gain term with the compressed pulse width.

Comment: @Seth, A little late to this but you are correct. At the end of the day, SNR is determined by the energy put into the pulse and not on the modulation used. You would include the compression gain when using the compressed pulsewidth, which then ultimately yields the real pulse width, ergo the energy put into the pulse.